# Extrusion Algorithm For Bezier Curves

Tags: algorithm, bezier-curve

I just posted this to SO but the question got closed, so I hope it's OK if I try it again here.  They say "we don’t allow questions seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries" so I'll only ask for help on the algorithm.

What's the best way to perform a simple extrusion effect to composite cubic Bezier curves (which I'll refer to as composite curves), like they are used in SVGs, similar to figure (5) in the picture below?  I want the result as a composite curve, not just the rasterization.

[image]

The mathematical formulation for this would be [dilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilation_(morphology)) with a structural element in the form of a line segment (which can be w.l.o.g. be the unit interval $[0, 1]$ embedded in $\mathbf{R}^2$).  So given a set $A$ of points in the plane whose boundary can be described by a composite curve, I am looking for a composite curve describing the set $A':=\{p+[0,1]:p\in A\}$ of points which are to the right of a point from $A$, but not further than distance $1$.

I imagine one must first find all points on a Bezier segment where the derivative of the curve is horizontal (unless the curve is a horizontal straight line) and divide the curve there.  Then horizontal straight lines are inserted between certain (new or old) curve segments.  If the shape has holes, the holes are just duplicated, moved to the right and intersected with the original hole.  Possibly related to [finding the points of inflection.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465703/finding-points-of-inflection-on-a-2d-bezier-curve)

My approach would be sampling the derivative of each curve segment at N points, look if the x-component of the derivative switches sign between two samples, then perform some kind of root finding algorithm to further contain the point where the sign switch happens.  Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: Yes it sounds reasonable, if you want examples in code you may want to look for pomax bezier info